# converting sql with multilevel joins to rails activerecord expression

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
'SELECT "complaints".* FROM "complaints" INNER JOIN "machines" ON "machines"."id" = "complaints"."machine_id" INNER JOIN "mclns" ON "machines"."mcln_id" = "mclns"."id" ORDER BY "mclns"."response_time" ASC'
```

I need the above sql to be converted to Active record statement

`complaint` model does not know about `mcln`
it has to go through `machine`

`Complaint.joins(:machine=>:mcln)` gives

```
SELECT "complaints".* FROM "complaints" INNER JOIN "machines" ON "machines"."id" = "complaints"."machine_id" INNER JOIN "mclns" ON "mclns"."machine_id" = "machines"."id"
```

but I need

```
SELECT "complaints".* FROM "complaints" INNER JOIN "machines" ON "machines"."id" = "complaints"."machine_id" INNER JOIN "mclns" ON "machines"."mcln_id" = "mclns"."id"
```

Update:

A machine can have a mcln and also many machines can have same mcln.

I have implemented it by using

`has_one :mcln` on `Machine` model and 
`belongs_to :machine` on `Mcln`

And I'm not sure if thats correct implementation.

Comment: What association do you have between machine and mcln?

Comment: well, I dont know what exactly to call it, but I think its one to many, a machine can have a mcln and also many machines can have same mcln, I have implemented it by using has_one :mcln on Machine model and belongs_to :machine on Mcln I'm not sure if thats correct implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your association is incorrect. If many machines can have the same mcln then the machines table should have a mcln_id column and your classes should look like

```
class Machine < AR::Base
  belongs_to :mcln
end

class Mcln < AR::Base
  has_many :machines
end
```

Then `Complaint.joins(:machine => :mcln)` should generate the SQL you want

Answer (score 0):

try out this :

```
SELECT complaints.*,machines.*,mclns.* FROM `complaints` 
INNER JOIN `machines` 
ON ( machines.id = complaints.machine_id )
INNER JOIN `mclns`
( ON machines.mcln_id = mclns.id )
```

Comment: sorry but I dont think you understood the question, I dont need an sql statement I need active record expression like `Complaint.joins(:machine=>:mcln)` but thanks anyway for trying to help